Text streaming with Langchain Ollama via Flask in Realtime
I am currently streaming output to frontend via Flask api and using Langchain with local Ollama model. The streaming works and I do receive output in frontend but its very slow and it first generates the stream in console and then send it to frontend as event stream.
How can I make the text stream as it is generated in realtime. Below is my code:
app.py:
@app.route('/search/<query>')
def search(query):
    def generate_stream(query):
        retrieved_info = mservice.retrieve_knowlede(query)
        for chunk in llm_service.query_knowledge(retrieved_info, final_query, model_name=Config.LLM.MODEL_NAME):
            if chunk.startswith("{"):
                yield f'data: {chunk}\n\n'
            else:
                lines = chunk.split('\n')
                for line in lines:
                    if line.strip():  # Only send non-empty lines
                        yield f'data: {line}\n\n'
                        time.sleep(0.12)
        yield ''

    return Response(generate_stream(final_query),
                    mimetype='text/event-stream')

LLM_Service.py:
@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=0.1, max=0.5), stop=stop_after_attempt(5), reraise=True)
    def query_knowledge(self, retrieved_info: List[Dict], query: str, model_name: str) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
        context = json.dumps(retrieved_info, indent=2)
       
        # First, stream the answer
        answer_stream = self._stream_answer(query, context, model_name)
        # Use a Future to store the streamed answer

        streamed_answer_future = Future()

        # Yield from _combine_streams, which will set the result of streamed_answer_future
        yield from self._combine_streams(answer_stream, streamed_answer_future)
        # Now that we have the full streamed answer, generate the full JSON
        json_future = self.executor.submit(self._generate_full_json, query, context, model_name,
                                           streamed_answer_future.result())
        # Yield the full JSON
        yield json.dumps(json_future.result())


    def _stream_answer(self, query: str, context: str, model_name: str) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
        prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template=_get_answer_prompt(),input_variables=["query", "context"])
        callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])
        gpt_model = ChatOllama(model=model_name, temperature=self.config.LLM.TEMPERATURE, callbacks=callback_manager)
        llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=gpt_model, prompt=prompt_template)
        return llm_chain.stream({"query": query, "context": context})

I have even tried calling the _answer_stream function directly but it doesn't make any difference.
